# Class Not Found even when specifying full package path

Tags: java, command-line, compilation

I'm trying to use a third-party package (call it 'foo.bar'). It's in a jar file in the current directory (foo.bar.jar). I'm trying to run the following super basic "hello-world"-style program:

```
package foo.bar.bla;
import foo.bar.*;
import foo.bar.somethingelse.SomeException;

public class HelloWorld implements SomethingInFooBar {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SomeException {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

It compiles just fine when I use `javac -cp foo.bar.jar HelloWorld.java`.

But when I try to run it (using `java HelloWorld`), I always get `NoClassDefFoundError (wrong name)` error, along with a `/`-separated package path (`some/path/like/this/HelloWorld`) of where the class ostensibly lies. But when I try to run it with the full path (as mentioned in other questions and on other sites addressing this problem), it still doesn't work (using the command `java path.it.gave.me.HelloWorld`).

Thanks for any insight into this n00b problem. I should stop relying so much on Eclipse!

Comment: If you execute your class with `java` you have also to declare the `foo.bar.jar` in the classpath. So: `java -cp foo.bar.jar HelloWorld`.

Comment: Duh whoops, I tried that with just HelloWorld and it didn't work, but it works when I specify the full path package as well (`java -cp foo.bar.jar path.it.gave.me.HelloWorld`). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally this happens because your classpath is not being set up properly. Try adding the classpath to the `java` call as well as the `javac` call, e.g., `java -cp foo.bar.jar path.to.HelloWorld`.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes Class Source Also Not Found Because Of Not Specifying Proper Class Source Folder Path In Java BuildPath --> Source Because Of Not Getting Class Files When It Required To Your Project.

Thats Why Also It Would Be Possible.

Answer (score 0):

try this line in terminal

`set classpath = .`

Answer (score -1):

```
java -cp foo.bar.jar foo.bar.bla.HelloWorld
```